# Opening calendar link

Tags: google-workspace

I created this registration form for registering clients to an event

I would like to add a google link in order to allow people to add the event to their calendar. I crated the event on Google first and got a link.

Have embedded the link into the form and then.... when clicking on the link from PC all works well

but when clicking on the link from mobile phone (which is what I expect more registrants will do), it opens google calendar but not with my event's details

it just shows today's date and event is empty.

I believe this is a google bug. Would appreciate any advice on how to solve it. This is so frustrating.

Thank you!